Isolating an application on an RDS server
I have an application I am running on an RDS server (Win Server 2022) and it won't run in more than one remote desktop user session. The second person that tries to run it gets this error "another copy of  is running on this machine".
I thought application processes run entirely separately in each user session? Somehow, this program knows it's running elsewhere and can't have separate instances running for separate user sessions. The software documentation doesn't specifically forbid it, they just say it's unsupported.
Can anyone offer a way to workaround this without having to create virtual machines for complete separate instances of Windows?
Thanks.

I thought application processes run entirely separately in each user session? Somehow, this program knows it's running elsewhere it's trivial in Windows to create a shared mutex and assign permission for other users to access it. The application can check for it when starting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c

it doesn't even have to be a mutex. The process could just call the list of other system processes, looking for a matching name. @robkblue, sure - any given process runs under a given user, but that doesn't mean that user x can't see the list of processes for user y.

Contact the vendor of the application and ask if you are licensed for multiple sessions running on one computer.
If this is allowed, ask what it would take for it to be supported. Without any details at all I cannot possibly say what the challenge is.  VDI aka everybody gets a VM could be a workaround.
Their developers can get help on multiple sessions if necessary. Including from Microsoft directly, of course they have seen many applications.
